# Is there any implementation difference between /dev/zero & /dev/null?

Tags: device-driver

I am trying to implement device driver for /dev/null & /dev/zero pseudo devices in C.

First, I would like to know how these two are different in usage?

My plan is to register these as /dev/null & /dev/zero and then in the corresponding write & read methods; just return success always.

Is above implementation correct?

Answer (score 4):

This documentation covers these pseudo-device files pretty well:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/zeros.html

You won't be able to register them as `/dev/null` and `/dev/zero`, since those things already exist. Unless you arrange to remove them, which I don't recommend, unless you have some very specific scenario requiring it, which it does not sound like you do.

`/dev/zero` is supposed to produce zeros, so just returning in the kernel write (interface with user space read) functions would not be adequate. Also, `/dev/null` must be able to read() (be written to) so it can consume data. Etc. etc.

I'm just starting to repeat that link, which is pointless. Check that link for a full description of the intended behavior.